# Single elementRef for all textbox

Tags: angular6

I have a table with a column holding textboxes.

Im using autocomplete on that textbox as follows:

```
 <tr *ngFor="let user of newUsers; index as i">
   .....
    <td>
          <input
          [matAutocomplete]="auto"
          placeholder="Select Manager" #salesManager>
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete"  [displayWith]="displayFn">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of filteredManager" [value]="tag" (onSelectionChange)="onSalesManagerChange(i,tag.name,tag.id)">
              <span>{{ tag.name | uppercase }}</span>
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Also I have code in ts file like below:

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
Observable.fromEvent(this.salesmanager.nativeElement, 'keyup')
.map((evt: any) => evt.target.value)
.debounceTime(1000)
  .subscribe((text: string) => this.changeManager(text));
```

}

The thing is `this.changeManager()` only executes on the first row of the table, it should also work on textboxes on other rows since it has `#salesManager` reference in the `.html`.

Comment: for the `#salesManager` reference you are propably using ViewChild(), but if you have in that reference 2 or more HTML elements, you need to use ViewChildren(), if you are not using it, the ViewChild takes automatically only the first element

Comment: ok let me try this...